# Boot failure dhcp service

Tags: dhcpd

Good evening everyone.
My dhcp server stopped working.
I pulled the status and features Failure.
If anyone can help me.

Follows AppendixA error image[image]

Script of service isc-dhcp-server status

```
root@jhn01:~# service isc-dhcp-server restart
root@jhn01:~# service isc-dhcp-server status
● isc-dhcp-server.service - ISC DHCP IPv4 server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/isc-dhcp-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Qui 2016-01-28 23:58:04 BRST; 6s ago
     Docs: man:dhcpd(8)
  Process: 1252 ExecStart=/bin/sh -ec      CONFIG_FILE=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf;      if [ -f /etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf ]; then CONFIG_FILE=/etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf; fi;      [ -e /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases ] || touch /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases;      exec dhcpd -user dhcpd -group dhcpd -f -4 -pf /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid -cf $CONFIG_FILE $INTERFACES (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 1248 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown dhcpd:dhcpd /run/dhcp-server (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1252 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 28 23:58:04 jhn01 sh[1252]: Can't open /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases for append.
Jan 28 23:58:04 jhn01 sh[1252]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Jan 28 23:58:04 jhn01 sh[1252]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Jan 28 23:58:04 jhn01 sh[1252]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Jan 28 23:58:04 jhn01 sh[1252]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Jan 28 23:58:04 jhn01 sh[1252]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Jan 28 23:58:04 jhn01 sh[1252]: exiting.
Jan 28 23:58:04 jhn01 systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, statu...ILURE
Jan 28 23:58:04 jhn01 systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 28 23:58:04 jhn01 systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Version S.O :
 Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Xenial Xerus (development branch)
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

Comment: It'd be really helpful if you could copy the text in the terminal and paste it into your question instead :).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in isc-dhcp-server/apparmor. See
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/isc-dhcp/+bug/1543794
for progress and possible workarounds